# Avoid clashes between table name and keywords psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a table in postgreSQL like the following but "USER" is a keyword and i am getting an error.

Btw shouldn't it work anyways since I am writing "User" instead of "USER"?

```
CREATE TABLE User(

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use reserved words for identifiers.  It is simple enough to change this to something like `Users`.

Second, Postgres by default insists that identifiers are case-insensitive by lower-casing them.  So, `User` and `USER` and `user` are the same thing -- and they all conflict with the keyword/reserved word.

All the rules about identifiers are pretty well explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

You can get around this by insisting on case-sensitivity by escaping the name:

```
 CREATE TABLE "User" ( . . .
```

But I strongly, strongly discourage this.  There are zillions of ways of constructing an identifier without having to reuse the few hundred reserved words.  Just be a little more creative in your naming.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and also the good practice tips :)